Compile OpenCV VideoWriter with mfx after Intel Media SDK discontinued
I am trying to use OpenCV VideoWriter with HW accel on Windows. The official doc said that mfx is the only option available for Windows. Currently, Intel is not offering official support for Media SDK link
Is there any other way to achieve HW accel for OpenCV VideoWriter on Windows platforms?
OpenCV Wiki link
Please let me know if any other techniques to enable HW accel for OpenCV VideoWriter on the Windows platform.
